# Google Chrome System Dark Mode

Tags: google-chrome, themes, chromium, 20.04

When I switch Ubuntu 20.04 to dark mode (via gnome-tweak-tool > appearance > Shell > Yaru-dark and the Appearance section of the system app) Google Chrome doesn't seem to think that my OS/System Preference is for a dark theme, as evidenced by the chrome settings section and dev tools being light-themed. [My dev tools are set to use a theme based on system preference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oht1i.png) I know the enable-force-dark experimental setting exists, but I don't want chrome to try and convert web pages to a dark theme by itself. Is there some sort of setting in dconf or elsewhere that will tell Google Chrome to render it's internal pages with a dark theme?

Comment: You can set Chrome to always start on dark mode by changing it's desktop entry file. See this answer to learn how to do this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1290268/1025464

Comment: @CarlosEduardo This question specifically asks to not try and convert webpages to dark mode and the linked answer applies to webUI (webpages) and force dark mode also applies to webpages too.

Comment: @mchid IIRC the `--force-dark-mode` switch in the linked answer is correct, but that also enable the feature to force dark mode on an pages (different switch).

Answer (score 4):

You must switch Google Chrome to GTK theme (Settings->Appearance->Themes) for make this works.

Comment: This is not sufficient to make chrome use the websites' dark themes. There is an open issue in Linux: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903. The only way to set dark mode properly as of Chrome 94.0 is to use the `--force-dark-mode` command line switch.

Comment: The issue has been fixed and will likely be available starting from Chrome 114

Comment: @Jespertheend yes but only in GTK - theme

Comment: @TarasH ah sorry I was mostly referring to the dark themes of web pages. The chromium bar at the top requires the GTK theme yeah.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest If I read it correctly, the question specifically asked for Google chrome to NOT try and use the websites dark themes and only apply this for settings, context menus, and dev console.

Comment: @mchid that switch does not force dark mode on every website. It will only make sites that explicitly want to match the system theme to turn dark. It's not the same as the [Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents](chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark) flag that makes every web site dark, which is the one the OP specifically do not want.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest I just feel that this answer answers the question and there's no need to apply this answer to webpages if the question didn't ask for it (that answer belongs to a different question).

Comment: @mchid It does not because there is (was?) a bug in which Google Chrome on Linux ignore the GTK system theme and need `--force-dark-mode` on startup.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
sudo nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

and set

```
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme
```

to `1`.

Comment: did not worked for me on Pop 21.04 hirsute & GNOME 3.38.3

Comment: Check if your `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable is set. If yes, use the path `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` as mentioned in the [configuration section of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#Configuration)

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke chrome with another theme like

```
env GTK_THEME="Yaru-dark" google-chrome --new-window
```

from your command line.

To change consistly, you have to edit your .desktop file:

If you are using gnome use the desktop file inside `~/.local/share/applications/` which looks like `chrome-xxxxxxxx.desktop`.

Change the line starting with Exec to :

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark google-chrome %U
```

Comment: A quick way to do this for all available profiles is to run: `sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark /g' ~/.local/share/applications/chrome*` and `sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark /g' ~/.local/share/applications/google*` If not using Yaru theme or if you just want to apply this generically regardless of your system theme: `sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark /g' ~/.local/share/applications/google*` and `sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark /g' ~/.local/share/applications/chrome*` This also works with `Adwaita:light` if you want light context menus.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 114,
finally it support Auto Dark Mode (and follow ubuntu system dark mode)

congratulations!

- no need `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1` (or 0)
  in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
- no need use GTK (or Classic) theme

tested

- on ubuntu 22 (gnome 42.5), chrome 114
- website

  - github Theme mode: Sync with system //OK
  - other site may work with extension `Dark Reader`'s Auto mode //Maybe

ref:
https://9to5google.com/2023/04/25/google-chrome-linux/

Comment: Hmm. Not working for me also on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, XFCE 4.16.1, Chrome 114.0.5735.133
Tested via GitHub -> Settings -> Appearance -> Theme Mode -> Sync with system

Comment: sorry for that. I didn't try xfce, I'm on gnome-shell @Colin'tHart