# How to make Snap Chromium follow dark theme preference?

Tags: themes, chromium

"Dark" and "GTK+" is selected in Ubuntu and Snap Chromium's Settings--Appearance. However Chromium's internal pages and websites are all using light theme, and only the title bar is dark. Firefox using "System theme - auto" shows dark theme for everything correctly.

There isn't a "Force dark theme" in chrome://flags now, and I tried "Auto dark mode for web contents" but it seems to just invert the color instead of telling the website to use dark theme (e.g. Github is still choosing "day theme" when using "sync with system").

Ubuntu 21.10

Chromium Version 98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229984/google-chrome-system-dark-mode. The .desktop file of Snap app is in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.

Comment: From the link above, just using the `--force-dark-mode` executable flag to force dark mode worked for me. Put that in a .desktop file to make Chrome easier to launch with that flag.