# How to force Chrome to use "prefers-color-scheme dark" - not using the emulated dark mode from Chrome flags?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to turn dark mode on for Chrome however, despite my system being set to dark mode, Chrome does not change websites as per their `prefers-color-scheme` query.

Suggestions in the previous questions point at using `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` to force dark mode, however this flag emulates dark mode on all websites - overriding and estimating what a dark mode would look like on that site.

[image]

This is undesirable. I am looking to have Chrome behave naturally as if it was informed that my system is using dark mode where, if a website doesn't have a dark mode configured, it won't be displayed as dark.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Try to run it like this: `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode`.
Here `--force-dark-mode` doesn't behave the same as `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`.
Here is a reference to update the default start command: https://askubuntu.com/a/1290268/1674617